# \rowcolor for a \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor

The `\multirow` text is covered by the background color. Does someone know why and can fix it?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{caption} 
    \label{tab} 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule
        & & A & B & C & D \\
        \midrule
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
            \multirow{2}{*}{Rosso}  & Pruning & - & - & 6-C-Pr & - \\
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
                                & Stalks & - & - & 6-C-S & - \\
            \multirow{2}{*}{Verde}  & Pruning & - & - & 6-M-Pr & - \\
                                & Stalks & - & - & 6-M-S & - \\
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
            \multirow{2}{*}{Blu}    & Pruning & 4-Pa-Pr & 5-Pa-Pr & 6-Pa-Pr & 7-Pa-Pr \\
        \rowcolor{gray!10}
                                & Stalks & 4-Pa-S & 5-Pa-S & 6-Pa-S & 7-Pa-S \\
            \multirow{2}{*}{Bianco}         & Pruning & - & - & 6-W-Pr & - \\
                                & Stalks & - & - & 6-W-Pr & - \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end {table}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE, would be helpful....

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but anyway you need to put the text on top of the colour not behind it so put the entry on the _last_ row and use a negative number of rows so it spans up. (unrelated but don't use `[h]` it normally just generates a warning that latex is changing it to ht)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the `\multirow` command is placed on the upper of the two rows, then its text is placed and the next table line with `\rowcolor` will overprint the lower part.
Therefore, `\multirow` is better moved to the lower of the two rows. Then the background color of the two rows is already set, when the text of `\multirow` is placed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{caption}
  \label{tab}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \toprule
    & & A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-C-Pr & -- \\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Rosso}
    & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-C-S & -- \\
    & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-M-Pr & -- \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Verde}
    & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-M-S & -- \\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Pruning & 4-Pa-Pr & 5-Pa-Pr & 6-Pa-Pr & 7-Pa-Pr \\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Blu}
    & Stalks & 4-Pa-S & 5-Pa-S & 6-Pa-S & 7-Pa-S \\
    & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-W-Pr & -- \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Bianco}
    & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-W-Pr & -- \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end {table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

I propose the following improvement to the table: as `booktabs` introduces vertical spacing around rules, which results in white strips in coloured rows, I replace the rule commands from booktabs  with variable width rule commands from the small `boldline` package, from the `shipunov` bundle, and add vertical padding above and below row cells with `cellspace` package, which ensures  a minimal vertical spacing at the top and the bottom of every cell of columns prefixed by the letter `S`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{caption}
  \label{tab}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{6}{Sc}}
    \hlineB{2}
    & & A & B & C & D \\
   \hlineB{1.25}
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-C-Pr & -- \\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Rosso}
    & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-C-S & -- \\
    & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-M-Pr & -- \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Verde}
    & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-M-S & -- \\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    & Pruning & 4-Pa-Pr & 5-Pa-Pr & 6-Pa-Pr & 7-Pa-Pr \\
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Blu}
    & Stalks & 4-Pa-S & 5-Pa-S & 6-Pa-S & 7-Pa-S \\
    & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-W-Pr & -- \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Bianco}
    & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-W-Pr & -- \\
    \hlineB{2}
  \end{tabular}
\end {table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `boldline` package is very attractive, but I can not find anything what remain on manual about this package :-(. The one page documentation is not very informative. Seems that this package define only `\hlineB{<thickness>}`. Can you point me, if somewhere is more information about it?

Comment: @Zarko: The only documentation is an example file. It defines `\hlineB, \clineB` and `V` for vertical rules (the latter replaces `|`, but is a column type really). The argument is a `number` (num times  `\linewidth`). The same functionality for horizontal rules only is possible with the `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` commands from `makecell`, with a `length` argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` with the following avantages:

- The colored rows will automatically respect the rules of `booktabs`.
- You don't have to put `\multicolumn` with a negative argument: you use `\Block` with a positive argument.
- You can color alternatively the logical rows with a command `\rowcolors` in the `\CodeBefore`.
- You will have a good output in all the PDF viewers at all levels of zoom (better than with `colortbl`).

There is a drawback: you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
\caption{caption}
\label{tab}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{6}{c}}[cell-space-limits=4pt]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!10}[respect-blocks]
\Body
  \toprule
  & & A & B & C & D \\
 \midrule
  \Block{2-1}{Rosso}
  & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-C-Pr & -- \\
  & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-C-S & -- \\
  \Block{2-1}{Verde}
  & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-M-Pr & -- \\
  & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-M-S & -- \\
  \Block{2-1}{Blu}
  & Pruning & 4-Pa-Pr & 5-Pa-Pr & 6-Pa-Pr & 7-Pa-Pr \\
  & Stalks & 4-Pa-S & 5-Pa-S & 6-Pa-S & 7-Pa-S \\
  \Block{2-1}{Bianco}
  & Pruning & -- & -- & 6-W-Pr & -- \\
  & Stalks & -- & -- & 6-W-Pr & -- \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end {table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]