# Table formatting problems: colouring, decimal alignment, row and column dimensions

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I am new to TeX and I have been encountering a few issues that I couldn't resolve on my own as I've been doing so far. I am wondering how to color the row while using the command `\multirow` without seeing only half of the writing of the merged cell. Also, how can I align the decimals (using the '.' and not ',') while remaining in the center of the cell? Lastly, how can I set the width of a column (and also the height of a row)? Sometimes I have wide columns when I don't need them or vice-versa.

Thank you in advance!!

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/filtrsecr}
\caption{Models of excretion rate for different molecules.}
\label{filtrsecr}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
     \small
        \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline \hline
& Unit & Filtered load & Amount reabsorbed & Amount secreted & Amount excreted & Filtered load \\
& & &  &  &  & reabsorbed (\%) \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{LightGreen}
$ Na^+ $ & $mEq/day$ & 25200 & 25410 & 0 & 150 & 99.4 \\
\rowcolor{Ivory}
$ Cl^- $ & $mEq/day$ & 18000 & 17850 & 0 & 150 & 99.2 \\
\rowcolor{LightGreen}
${HCO_3}^- $& $mEq/day$ & 4320 & 4318 & 0 & 2 & 99.9 \\
\rowcolor{Ivory}
$ K^+ $& $mEq/day$ & 720 & 620 & 50 & 100 & 86.1 \\

\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{LightGreen} $Ca^{2+}$}
& \cellcolor{LightGreen} $mEq/day$ & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 540 & \cellcolor{LightGreen}530 & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 0 & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 10 & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 98.1 \\ 
\cellcolor{Ivory} & \cellcolor{Ivory} $mmol/day$ & \cellcolor{Ivory} 270 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 265 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 0 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 5 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 98.1 \\

\multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor{LightGreen} ${HPO_4}^{2-}$}
& \cellcolor{LightGreen} $mEq/day$ & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 260 & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 234 & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 0 & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 26 & \cellcolor{LightGreen} 90 \\
\cellcolor{Ivory} & \cellcolor{Ivory} $mmol/day$ & \cellcolor{Ivory} 144 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 130 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 0 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 14 & \cellcolor{Ivory} 90 \\ 

\rowcolor{LightGreen}
$ Urea $ & $mmol/day$ & 870 & 460 & 0 & 410 & 52.9 \\
\rowcolor{Ivory}
$ Glucose $ & $mmol/day$ & 800 & 799.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 99.9 \\
\rowcolor{LightGreen}
$ Uric\ acid $ & $mmol/day$ & 50 & 49 & 4 & 5 & 98 \\
\rowcolor{Ivory}
$ Creatinine $ & $mmol/day$ & 12 & 0 & 1 & 12 & 0 \\
\rowcolor{LightGreen}
$ Total\ solute $ & $mmol/day$ & 50386 & 49541.5 & 55 & 848.5 & 98 \\
\rowcolor{Ivory}
$ Water $ & $ml/day$ & 180000 & 179000 & 0 & 1000 & 99.4 \\
    \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Filtration, reabsorption, secretion and excretion rates referring to each substance \cite{RefWorks:130}.}
    \label{filtreabsecret}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: For the usage of `rowcolor` with `multirow` you can have a look at the following link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269549/134144 Alignment of numbers in cells can be achieved by using the `S` column of the `siunitx` package. In your current setup coumn widths are calculated automatically. For fixed width colmns you could use `p` cells. For individual handling of linebreaks in single cells, the `makecell` package might be useful as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always ask only one question per question. And please always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  instead of code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, which requires a few more packages, amongst which `chemformula` which has a command  to type chemistry formulae and reactions in a simple way and `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in standard cells. I propose a design with `hhline`, which looks nicer than the default `\hline`s with coloured rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx, longtable, multirow, booktabs, hhline, makecell, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\mEq}{mEq}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/filtrsecr}
  \sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
  \caption{Models of excretion rate for different molecules.}
  \label{filtrsecr}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
  \small\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
  \setlength{\doublerulesep}{5pt}
  \rowcolors{3}{LightGreen}{Ivory}
  \begin{tabular}{|Cc||Cr|S[table-format=6.0]|S[table-format=6.1]| S[table-format=2.0]|S[table-format=4.1]|S[table-format=2.1]|}
    \hhline{~------}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Unit} & {\thead{Filtered \\ load}} & {\thead{Amount\\ reabsorbed}} & {\thead{Amount\\ secreted}} & {\thead{Amount\\ excreted}} & {\thead{Filtered load\\ reabsorbed\\ (\%)}} \\
    \hhline{-::======:}
    \ch{Na+} & \si{\mEq/\day} & 25200 & 25410 & 0 & 150 & 99.4 \\
    \ch{Cl-} & \si{\mEq/\day} & 18000 & 17850 & 0 & 150 & 99.2 \\
    \ch{HCO_3-} & \si{\mEq/\day} & 4320 & 4318 & 0 & 2 & 99.9 \\
    \ch{K+ } & \si{\mEq/\day} & 720 & 620 & 50 & 100 & 86.1 \\
                                                            & \si{\mEq/\day} & 540 & 530 & 0 & 10 & 98.1 \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{Ivory}\ch{Ca^{2+}}} & \si{\mmol/\day} & 270 & 265 & 0 & 5 & 98.1 \\
    \cellcolor{LightGreen} & \si{\mEq/\day} & 260 & 234 & 0 & 26 & 90 \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{LightGreen}\ch{HPO_4^{2-}}} & \si{\mmol/\day} & 144 & 130 & 0 & 14 & 90 \\
    Urea & \si{\mmol/\day} & 870 & 460 & 0 & 410 & 52.9 \\
    Glucose & \si{\mmol/\day} & 800 & 799.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 99.9 \\
    Uric\ acid & \si{\mmol/\day} & 50 & 49 & 4 & 5 & 98 \\
    Creatinine & \si{\mmol/\day} & 12 & 0 & 1 & 12 & 0 \\
    Total\ solute & \si{\mmol/\day} & 50386 & 49541.5 & 55 & 848.5 & 98 \\
    Water & \si{\ml/\day} & 180000 & 179000 & 0 & 1000 & 99.4 \\
    \hhline{-||------}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Filtration, reabsorption, secretion and excretion rates referring to each substance \cite{RefWorks:130}.}
  \label{filtreabsecret}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you have `unicode` problem with your editor again : -).  please correct  `HCO₃-` to `HCO_3-`  and `HPO₄^{2-}` to `HPO_4^{2-}` .

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks for warning me. I'll fix it within a few seconds!

Comment: What is the difference between Cc and Cr, both used in the definition of the tabular environment?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I forgot to explain this technical point. `C` is a prefix before the standard specifiers `c` and `r`,  to add the minimal vertical padding  defined by `cellspace` at the top and bottom of cells (`\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit`). Normally, the letter `S`should be used (`Sc` and `Sr`), but with `siunitx`, which defines `S` columns, we have to use `C`. So the first column is centred (with padding) whereas the second is right-aligned (I thought it looked nicer this way).

Comment: Also, how do you decide the number under the name of table-format, in square brackets after S?

Comment: Looking at the elements in the column: for instance, in the 4th column, numbers have at most 6digits before the decimal dot, and at most 1 decimal digit, so the table-format will be `6.1`.