# Problem with Multirows

Tags: tables, multirow

[image: 3rd row is halfway cut]

How can I fix the 3rd row? The word is halfway cut.

```
\begin{center}
    \centering
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
  \captionof{table}{aa} \label{tab:t1}
  \vspace{0.3cm}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    External Stimulus & Dimension & Material & Fabrication Technique & Ref.\\
    \hline
    Temperature & Some values & Some values & qq & 1\\   \hline 
    \multirow{2}*{Light} & Some values & Some values & rr &2\\\cline{2-5}
    & Some values & Some values & zz &3\\\hline
    Magnetic field & Some values & Some values & d & 4\\\hline
    pH & 3D & e & mm & 5\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put "Light" on the last row of the multirow, and use `\multirow{-2}*{Light}` instead.

In other words, change to

```
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
    \rowcolor{gray!50}
    External Stimulus & Dimension & Material & Fabrication Technique & Ref.\\
    \hline
    Temperature & Some values & Some values & qq & 1\\   \hline 
    & Some values & Some values & rr &2\\\cline{2-5}
    \multirow{-2}*{Light} & Some values & Some values & zz &3\\\hline
    Magnetic field & Some values & Some values & d & 4\\\hline
    pH & 3D & e & mm & 5\\
  \end{tabular}
```

The reason is that currently the code draws the first row of the `Light` rows, with the text drawn offset to be low, and *then* it draws the second row. But when you draw the second row with the background color, it paints over the lowered text from the first row. So to fix it, draw all background first and *then* put the text. More detailed explanation is given on pages 8-9 of the `multirow` package manual.

I am not sure whether this works well with the `\rowcolors` specification. You may need to color each row individually.

Comment: Hm... I should've searched TeX.SE _before_ I wrote the answer. Better explanations and alternative solutions are available at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269547/119 some of which works also with automatic row coloring.

Comment: I can confirm it does work with `\rowcolors`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` with a perfect result in all the PDF viewers (no thin white lines).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{aa} \label{tab:t1}
  \vspace{0.3cm}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c}
  \CodeBefore
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}[respect-blocks]
    \rowcolor{gray!50}{1}
  \Body
    External Stimulus & Dimension & Material & Fabrication Technique & Ref.\\
    \hline
    Temperature & Some values & Some values & qq & 1\\   \hline 
    \Block{2-1}{Light} & Some values & Some values & rr &2\\\cline{2-5}
    & Some values & Some values & zz &3\\\hline
    Magnetic field & Some values & Some values & d & 4\\\hline
    pH & 3D & e & mm & 5\\
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]